# How to get elementI function c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to add some function to my code, but I cant get all my parameters right:

```
class Peak {            
    };

    class Ceil{

    };

    struct LessPath
    {
    };
    void aStar(priority_queue<Peak, vector<Peak>, LessPath> *openList, vector<vector<Ceil>> *ceiledMaze, int curY, int curX, int destY, int destX);

    int main(){
        aStar(&openList, &ceiledMaze, KY, KX, 100,200);
    } 

    void aStar(priority_queue<Peak, vector<Peak>, LessPath> *openList, vector<vector<Ceil>> *ceiledMaze, int curY, int curX, int destY, int destX)
            {
                cerr <<"element X - " << ceiledMaze[curY][curX])<<endl;    
            }
```

How to get value of **ceiledMaze[curY][curX]** in the function?

Comment: dont pass pointers (unless you want to allow for `nullptr` in which case you should check for it) pass a reference instead and remove the bracket that is too much `..[curX])` -> `...[curX]`, then it should be fine

Comment: btw your question should contain a [mcve] and the error message you get

Comment: Pass by reference instead of pointer and your life will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cerr << "element X - " << (*ceiledMaze)[curY][curX]) << endl;
```

...You're passing a pointer so beside the fact you should also check for ranges,nullptr,etc., you were accessing it as direct element "vector" - without dereference.

next you could try something like passing by reference:

```
int main(){
    aStar(openList, ceiledMaze, KY, KX, 100,200);
} 

void aStar(priority_queue<Peak, vector<Peak>, LessPath>& openList, vector<vector<Ceil>>& ceiledMaze, int curY, int curX, int destY, int destX)
{
    cerr <<"element X - " << ceiledMaze[curY][curX])<<endl;    
}
```